# Giving preference to one operator[] over another

Tags: c++

Consider the following class:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test( char );
    Test( int );
    operator const char*();
    int operator[]( unsigned int );
};
```

When I use it:

```
Test t;
Test& t2 = t[0];
```

I get a compiler error where it can't figure out which operator[] to use. MSVC and Gcc both. Different errors. But same problem.

I know what is happening. It can construct a Test from either an int or a char, and it can either use `Test::operator[]` or it can cast to const char* and use the built `char*[]`.

I'd like it to prefer `Test::operator[]`.

Is there a way to specify a preference like this?

UPDATE: First, I'll agree with response below that there is no language feature that lets you specify a priority for conversions. But like juanchopanza found below - you can create such a preference indirectly by making one conversion require no casts, and make the other require a cast. E.g. `unsigned int` as the argument for `operator[]` won't work but, using `int` will.

The default index argument is unsigned - for gcc and msvc anyway - so making the index argument unsigned will cause the compiler to prefer the right operator.

@Konrad: about implicit conversions to built-in types. Agree generally. But I need it in this case.

Comment: Interestingly, my gcc 4.8 snapshot doesn't get confused by this. It just produces the error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Test&' from an rvalue of type 'int'`

Comment: @juanchopanza So does g++ 4.8 accept the code if you change the reference to const?

Comment: @john yes, and so does 4.6.3. After modifications to make it compile (adding a default constructor and some empty or trivial implementations of the constructors and operators)

Comment: @juanchopanza Interesting. But I think it's best to stay away from dubious constructs like this. Whatever the standard says, in practice compilers are going to disagree.

Comment: @juanchopanza: My real example is somwhat more complex than the code above. But the principle is the same. When I matched the index argument to the exact type it was expecting ( from the error message ) the problem went away.

Comment: @john I agree completely. Follow the principle of least surprise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't. And this kind of ambiguity is why automatic conversions to another type (like `operator char*`) are not recommended.

Comment: No is an acceptable answer to my question: e.g. that there is no language feature to prioritize conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You can always make the constructors `explicit` – or, as john has noted, omit the conversion operator. I’d usually recommend doing all of these things but since your code is a toy example it’s hard to say what is appropriate in your situation.

That said, the following should work:

```
Test const& t2 = t.operator[](0);
```

(Note the added `const` – otherwise you’d bind a temporary to non-const reference which doesn’t work either.)

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented container classes like yours before -- it is entirely possible to avoid ambiguity problems while maintaining a clean, intuitive syntax.

First, you need to take const-ness into account.  Usually, a const char* cast will not modify the object, so make this a const member function:

```
operator const char*() const;
```

Also, your [] operator is returning an int instead of int&, so this should probably be const too:

```
int operator[]( unsigned int ) const;
```

If you want to be able to assign a value to an indexed element (mytest[5]=2), you would add another operator function like this (this doesn't replace the const version above -- keep both):

```
int& operator[](unsigned int);
```

Next, you will want to accept indexes that are not just unsigned int.  A literal integer has the int type.  To avoid problems related to index type, you need to overload operator for alternatives.  These overloads will just static_cast the index to your native index type and pass it to the native overload (the one for the native index type).  One of these overloads might look like:

```
int operator[]( int idx ) const {
    return operator[]( static_cast<unsigned int>(idx) ); 
}
```

Instead of adding a bunch of overloads, you could use a single template member function to cover all possibilities.  The template function will get used for any index types that do not already have a non-template overload.  And this preference for non-template overloads is unambiguous.  Essentially, this implements your request for a preferred operator, but const-ness is not templatable, so two versions would be required if you have a const and a non-const [] operator.  This catch-all member function might look like this (keep in mind that its definition must stay in your class' declaration and cannot be moved to an implementation file):

```
template <typename IT>
int operator[]( const IT& idx ) const {
    return operator[]( static_cast<unsigned int>(idx) );
}
```

If you added a non-const version of the [] operator, then you would also need:

```
template <typename IT>
int& operator[]( const IT& idx ) {
    return operator[]( static_cast<unsigned int>(idx) );
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: In my real class I was already doing most of these things. But I didn't think to templatize my class operator[]. I'll try that, thanks.